# How to do row-wise element multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a matrix `[[x1, x2, x3], 
               [y1, y2, y2], 
               [z1, z2, z3]]`

How can I do [x1*y1*z1 , x2*y2*z2, x3*y3*z3] in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`tf.reduce_prod(x, 0)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_prod), because you multiply numbers along the columns:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
b = tf.reduce_prod(a, 0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tf.reduce_prod was what I was looking for. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_prod